# nginx let's encrypt SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

My own server suddenly sends this error
"SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

I am using an Nginx server and Let's encrypt. The error began today out of the blue.

my API is coded in Laravel running on php7.3-fpm. My server is up to date with all packages.

I force a renewal of the certificate. I if check the SSL certificate in a browser it says all is good.

But I simply don't know why my site sends back the ssl certificate problem untop of the api response.
Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: We are seeing the same issue today. For now, we have added SSL_VERIFYPEER as false and that worked. But this is likely a letsencrypt issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error message with `git` today follow a fresh NetBSD install.  Following the `pkgin install samba-4` which pulled in `mozilla-rootcerts`, I neglected to follow the post install instructions to:

```
# mozilla-rootcerts install
```

Once the certs were installed into `/etc/openssl/certs`, `git clone` worked.  I would suspect any tool, like `curl`, requiring TLS/SSL certs will now work too.